# Create a local MS SQL Database on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, development, database

I need to do some tests on a MS SQL (not MySQL) database. But without the burden of having to open a hosting account, create a remote database, connect to it, and remotely insert a million records.

I need to create a MS SQL Database *locally* on my computer only to be used on my computer - and I need to be able to import it using Navicat software.

How can we create a *local* MS SQL database on OS X [Yosemite]?

Comment: Parallels, VMWare Fusion or Virtual Box + Windows + MSSQL Server

Comment: MS SQL server only runs on Windows and so you need a VM or run in Bootcamp

Comment: @sdmeyers: That should be under Your Answer, not a comment.